# C# Linq IQueryable select flattened nested object list

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string ParentPropertyA { get; set; }
    public string ParentPropertyA { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children{get; set;}

}

public class Child
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public string ChildPropertyA { get; set; }
    public string ChildPropertyB { get; set; }
}

private static Expression<Func<Parent, dynamic>> BuildModel()
{
    return x => new
    {
        x.ParentId,
        x.Children
    };
}
```

I use this expression on `IQueryable.Select(BuildModel())`

Let's say I have a `Parent` object with two `Children`... 
Given that structure how can I achieve returning two records with all `Parent` properties and with specific `Children`, instead of just one `Parent` with two `Children`?

Example:

```
{
  ParentId: 1,
  ParentPropertyA: "parentA",
  ParentPropertyB: "parentB",
  Children:
  [
    {
      ChildId: 1,
      ChildPropertyA: "childA1",
      ChildPropertyB: "childB1"
    },
    {
      ChildId: 2,
      ChildPropertyA: "childA2",
      ChildPropertyB: "childB2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Instead, I want to have them returned as:

```
[
  {
    ParentId: 1,
    ParentPropertyA: "parentA",
    ParentPropertyB: "parentB",
    ChildId: 1,
    ChildPropertyB: "childB1"
  },
  {
    ParentId: 1,
    ParentPropertyA: "parentA",
    ParentPropertyB: "parentB",
    ChildId: 2,
    ChildPropertyB: "childB2"
  }
]
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at SelectMany()

Comment: Did you mean to leave out `ChildPropertyA` in your final example?

Comment: @NetMage Yes, purposely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` over the parent collection. Within the SelectMany expression, select the children, and pair it with a copy of the parent.

```
var flattenedList = parents.SelectMany
(
    p => p.Children.Select
    (
        c => new { Parent = p, Child = c } 
    )
);
```

This will give you one element per child, with parents duplicated as needed.

Comment: It worked, thanks! However I'm getting exception when calling flattenedList.Count()
System.NotSupportedException
There is a workaround for this?

Comment: Perhaps `ToList().Count` ? Or start another question.

Answer (score 0):

DTO class:

```
public class DTO
{
   public int ParentId { get; set; }
   public string ParentPropertyA { get; set; }
   public string ParentPropertyB { get; set; }
   public int ChildrenId { get; set; }
   public string ChildrenPropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
var parent = GetParent() //Get Parent instance

List<Dto> dtos = parent.Childrens.Select(q => new DTO
{
    ParentId = parent.ParentId,
    ParentPropertyA = parent.ParentPropertyA
    ParentPropertyB = parent.ParentPropertyB,
    ChildrenId = q.ChildrenId,
    ChildrenPropertyB = q.ChildrenPropertyB
})
.ToList();
```

Comment: Where is `ChildrenPropertyA` ? And this `DTO` does not look like OP's parent dto

Comment: `ChildrenPropertyA` is not used, according to the example provided by OP, so I did not include it in DTO.